# how to add multiple records in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

how  to add multiple records in mysql using php. Is using array the only solution to this problem. Because I tried using array but the record that would be added in the database would look like this:
array

Comment: Can you provide more details and your code source ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a multivalue insert statement (INSERT... VALUES (record1), (record2) etc)
(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

This is how you can construct such a statement from array of records

```
$values = array();
foreach($records_array as $record)
    $values[] = sprintf("( '%s' , '%s' )", addslashes($record['name']), addslashes($record['email']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, email) VALUES " . implode(",", $values);
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: A good post but NOTE: use mysql_real_escape_string instead of addslashes!!!!!!! http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: it stands for string replace of the params `addslashes($record['name'])` supplied

Answer (score 3):

You need to go through each member of the array:

```
foreach($array as $record)
 {   ...  }
```

and perform an INSERT query for each member or - better for performance - insert all records in one statement as outlined in [user187291's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123349/how-to-add-multiple-records-in-mysql-using-php/2123383#2123383).

Comment: It would be better to perform it all as one query instead of having to hit the DB for each iteration. No?

Comment: True. @stereofrog's answer outlines how. I didn't know VALUES can do multiple rows at once!